# HP Spectre x360 webcam is showing very low quality

Tags: webcam

I have a HP Spectre x360 laptop and I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. The webcam image is poor quality: the resolution is bad, if it's a little dark in a room it get's terrible quickly, and there is often a purple tinge to colours.

I think that it has been like this since I bought it a few years ago.

I downloaded guvcview, but playing with the settings didn't improve the webcam quality at all. Perhaps the webcam itself is broken.

I'm open to any other suggestions of how I could improve this. Thank you.

Comment: Does it work any better in Windows? Have you tried booting from a Live USB of a more recent version of Ubuntu? Are you using the HWE kernel  or the original kernel version for Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I don't have Windows on this laptop so I'm not sure if it works any better. I haven't tried booting from a Live USB, but I could perhaps try that. I had the same problems years ago when I was using Ubuntu 16.04. Apparently my kernel is 4.15.0-96-generic.

Comment: Please update the question with kernel and other information and try with Live USB of 19.10 and 20.04. Version 20.04 LTS will be out by the end of the week, but you can try the beta version for this experiment. If newer kernels don't have a fix, I am out of ideas.